# What are the most useful Smart Packages for Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, atmosphere

I'm starting to learn Meteor and found that knowing of several smart packages can greatly speed up development.

What are some of the most useful Smart Packages that you wish you knew when you first started? Like `router`, `accounts-base`, `accounts-ui` etc... Atmosphere doesn't have a sort-by-popularity function.

Comment: I am also interested in knowing this.

Comment: Just want to note the url for Atmospher as some users may come here looking for info on where to find the package list: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I agree that some kind of popularity sort similar to [npmjs](https://npmjs.org/) would be awesome.</s>

[Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com/) now has a really helpful [scoring system](http://blog.percolatestudio.com/engineering/atmosphere-score/) based on number of downloads, recent updates, etc.

While a lot of atmosphere packages are convenient wrappers around existing projects, there are some with original content that are **extremely** useful. My favorites are:

- [iron-router](http://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router)
- [kadira](http://atmospherejs.com/package/kadira)
- [subs-manager](http://atmospherejs.com/package/subs-manager)
- [publish-with-relations](http://atmospherejs.com/package/publish-with-relations)